# Create a protected route in React based on state

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create a route that can only be accessed by people with a specific role. This role is set in the state (I am using redux) once the user logs in, however it seems like the Private Route component is only getting the initial state. I need the PrivateAdminRoute component to update on state change, and it doesn't seem like it is doing that. This is my App.js:

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const loggedInData = useSelector(state => state.loggedInData.loggedIn);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/api/users/current')
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data === "") {
          dispatch(signOut());
        } else {
          dispatch(signIn(res.data.role, res.data.firstName));
        }
      });
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <PrivateAdminRoute path="/admin" component={Admin} role={loggedInData.role} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my PrivateAdminRoute component:

```
const PrivateAdminRoute = (props) => {
    return <Route path={props.path} render={(props) => (
                    props.role === 'Admin' ? <Admin /> : <Redirect to='/' />
                )}
            />
}

export default PrivateAdminRoute;
```

And here is my reducer:

```
const loggedReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SIGN_IN':
            return {
                ...state,
                loggedIn: {
                    isLogged: true,
                    role: action.payload.role,
                    username: action.payload.name
                }
            }
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
            return {
                ...state,
                loggedIn: {
                    isLogged: false,
                    role: "None",
                    username: ""
                }
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this caused by your shadowed parameter names? You have `props` for the `PrivateAdminRoute` component and then you have `props` again for the `render` property of the `Route` component. `props` provided for the `render` function only has the router supplied properties and does not include the ones provided to your `PrivateAdminRoute` component.

Comment: That's a good catch - do you know how I should pass the ```props``` I want to the render function? I changed the name of what I was passing in but that did not fix my current issue.

Comment: Just changing the name of one of the parameters and then accessing the property using the correct name would have been enough if that was the issue. Usually I would attempt to minimise the number of anonymous functions and instead of doing the swap in the render of the route do something more along the lines of `props.role === 'Admin' ? <route path={props.path} component={Admin} /> : <Redirect to="/" />`. Have you ensured that the value has been updated in Redux and that you are generating new state and not updating the old state?

Comment: I'll update my question with my reducer just in case something is there - the state is definitely getting updated as it shows as updated in the redux dev tools

Comment: Your reducer looks like it should be functioning as you would expect. I created a quick test case example using  useReducer instead of a redux store and it seems to function as you would expect: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ebbpws?file=index.tsx

Comment: Interesting after looking at your example I guess I need a ```Link``` for this to work - as soon as I add that in it works perfectly but if I just type in the proper url it doesn't work. I can work with that though I think thanks for your help I really appreciate you taking the time!

Comment: Typing in the proper URL would be making it check the role and redirect before the user is loaded. You would need to add a loading state, and not render the routes until after the user has logged in.